# multi-select component in jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there any component in jquery for multiselect.  a kind of autocomplete. upon selecting the value from the dropdown(autocomplete) it should get place in the textbox with a cross at the end. we can delete it upon clicking the cross. incase of multiple values selected , multiple values ll be present in it with a cross

Comment: KENDO UI has a good multiselect. Not sure about jquery UI. Its website does not mention anything.

Answer (score 0):

jquery UI has this one. 
http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/

Multiple values can be selected by pressing CTRL. If that is what you want.
If you have limited items in your list then this will work out fine.